# Max shipping cost

Tags: prestashop

How do I set the maximum shipment amount per 199 in PrestaShop 1.7?

It may be smaller, but it may not exceed 199.

In which file do I look for the variable corresponding to the amount of the shipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override function `getPackageShippingCost()` from `Cart` class:

```
class Cart extends CartCore 
{
    public function getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier = null, $use_tax = true, Country $default_country = null, $product_list = null, $id_zone = null)
    {
        $shipping_cost = parent::getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier, $use_tax, $default_country, $product_list, $id_zone);

        if ($shipping_cost > 199) {
            return 199;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to remove `class_index.php` and clear cache.

Comment: Thanks! 
everything works, only the line:
$shipping_cost = parent::getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier, $use_tax, $default_country, $product_list, $id_zone);
charges the carrier's shipping cost
In the store, the prices of carriers have been set at 0, while the additional shipping cost in each product determines the price of delivery.

Comment: so how to get the actual delivery cost along with "additional costs" from the product card :-)

Comment: It's already added at parent's `getPackageShippingCost` function: `// Additional Shipping Cost per product
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if (!$product['is_virtual']) {
                $shipping_cost += $product['additional_shipping_cost'] * $product['cart_quantity'];
            }
        }`